# Sometimes socket communication is too slow in Dart

Tags: flutter, kotlin, sockets, ipc

I'm making a socket module which connecting between flutter and android as localhost.

The reason why i use socket is simple.
"I have to communicate flutter and android(or ios) as synchronously".

Anyway, My question is below.

I made some socket communication code like this

```kotlin
package com.example.flutter_socket_test

import android.util.Log
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class AndroidClientSocket {

    lateinit var socket: Socket
    lateinit var writer: OutputStreamWriter
    lateinit var reader: BufferedReader

    val TAG = "SocketTest"

     val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    init{
        Thread{
            socket = Socket("localhost", 9999)
            socket.tcpNoDelay = true

            writer = OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
            reader = BufferedReader(socket.getInputStream().reader(), 1024)
        }.start()
    }




    fun doSomeFunction(id: Int, name: String, age: Int, method: String): String {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val payload =  JSONObject()
        payload.put("id", id)
        payload.put("name", name)
        payload.put("age", age)

        val json = JSONObject()
        json.put("method", method)
        json.put("payload", payload)

        val response = sendMessage(json.toString())
        Log.e(TAG, "Taking time : ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms")
        return response
    }

    fun sendMessage(json: String):String {
        val response = executor.submit<String> {
            var result = "a"
            writer.write(json)
            writer.flush()
            result = reader.readLine()
            return@submit  result
        }
        return response.get()

    }

    fun dispose(){
        socket.close()
    }
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_test/rf_unity_room.dart';

class MainProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late final ServerSocket socket;

  final MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel("com.example.flutter_socket_test");

  final Map<int, RfUnityRoom> _unityRooms = {};
  Map<int, RfUnityRoom> get unityRooms => _unityRooms;

  String state = "{}";

  MainProvider() {
    _init();
  }

  void _init() async {
    await _initializeServerSocket();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeServerSocket() async {
    socket = await ServerSocket.bind("localhost", 9999);

    socket.listen((Socket clientSocket) async {
      clientSocket.listen((event) async {
        Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(event));
        clientSocket.writeln(jsonEncode({"method": json["method"], "status": "success", "data": json}));
        await clientSocket.flush();
      });
    });
  }

  void createAndroidSocket() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod("init");
  }

  void callMethod() async {
    state = await _channel.invokeMethod("call", {"id": 1, "name": "Flutter Tester", "age": 29});
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteAndroidSocket() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod("dispose");
  }
}
```

After writing this code, I tried test socket communication as 100 times using for-loop. here is the result log.

```
Reloaded 2 of 964 libraries in 293ms (compile: 56 ms, reload: 138 ms, reassemble: 58 ms).
D/EGL_emulation(29797): app_time_stats: avg=569600.81ms min=569600.81ms max=569600.81ms count=1
D/TrafficStats(29797): tagSocket(5) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/EGL_emulation(29797): app_time_stats: avg=79969.91ms min=79969.91ms max=79969.91ms count=1
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 4 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 4 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 44 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 45 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 0 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 3 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 42 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 4 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 3 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 7 ms
D/EGL_emulation(29797): app_time_stats: avg=19.25ms min=1.00ms max=406.38ms count=37
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 48 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 3 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 45 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 3 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 0 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 44 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 45 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 0 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 43 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 44 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 0 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 1 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 2 ms
E/SocketTest(29797): Taking time : 0 ms
I/Choreographer(29797): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I know socket is very fast. but sometimes, it takes almost 43~45ms. I don't know why. could you explain why this situations happen?

Actually, I cannot find any way to solve this problem...